# Как на Java распарсить строку?

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения, split

Имеется строка вида: яяяя,ччччч,"цццццц, ццццццццц",ввввввв

Мой код:

```
String[] array = myList.get(13).split(",");
Arrays.stream(array).forEach(System.out::println);
```

в результате выдает массив с элементами через все запятые.

Вопрос - как часть строки в кавычках сделать одним элементом

Comment: Парсить строку на токены и выкусывать токены по кавычкам, а не только по запятым

Comment: `.split(",(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)")` - https://ideone.com/Pzzv1l

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Регулярное выражение для `split`: `str.split(",(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)")`:

```java
System.out.println("split");
String str = "яяяя,ччччч,\"цццццц, ццццццццц\",,ввввввв";
Arrays.stream(str.split(",(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)"))
      .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Регулярное выражение для `match`:

```java
System.out.println("----\nmatch");
Pattern csv = Pattern.compile("\"[^\"]*\"|[^,]+|(?=,)(?<=,)");
csv.matcher(str)
   .results()
   .map(MatchResult::group)
   .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Результаты:

```
split
яяяя
ччччч
"цццццц, ццццццццц"

ввввввв
----
match
яяяя
ччччч
"цццццц, ццццццццц"

ввввввв
```